# Who owns autorelease objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

In objective-c manual it is written that something like

```
return [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

can be done and then `release` is not necessary at any point, even not in the function that received this object. Who owns this object then? when will it be released?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current `NSAutoreleasePool` does and will take care of the releasing when drained.

`IBAction` calls get wrapped into an `NSAutoreleasePool` that gets drained after the call.

For all non-IBAction calls the following would apply:

Say, you have these methods:

```
- (id)foo {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    SomeClass *bar = [self bar]; //bar still exists here
    //do other stuff
    //bar still exists here
    //do other stuff
    //bar still exists here
    [pool drain]; //bar gets released right here!
    //bar has been released
}

- (id)bar {
    return [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease]; //bar will still be around after the return
}
```

Consider another scenario:

```
- (void)foo {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    //do other stuff
    [self bar];
    //do other stuff
    [pool drain]; //the string from blee would be released right here;
}

- (void)bar {
    [self baz];
}

- (void)baz {
    NSString *string = [self blee];
}

- (id)blee {
    return [NSString string]; //autoreleased
}
```

As you can see the autoreleased string object did not even have to be used in or get returned to the scope in which the pool was created.

NSAutoreleasePools exist on a stack (one per thread) and autoreleased objects get owned by the pool that's topmost at the time of the call to `autorelease`.

---

Update:
If you are dealing with a tight loop and want to keep the memory moderately low while not slowing down your loop, consider doing something like this:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    [NSString stringWithString:@"foo"];
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
        [pool drain];
        pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    }
}
[pool drain];
```

However `NSAutoreleasePool` is highly optimized, so one pool per iteration usually isn't much of a problem.

---

To fully understand how NSAutoreleasePools work read this [excellent article by Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-02-lets-build-nsautoreleasepool.html)

Comment: If you explicitly created it, it is drained when you call [pool drain] (best practice) or when the pool itself is deallocated [pool release]. If you're using the implicit autorelease pool, that is managed by the run loop and in principle is drained each time around.

Comment: Can I forecebly make an autoreleased object be released when I know I don't need it anymore without the need of creating 123434 pools if I'm in a tight loop or something?

Comment: @Regexident: its still much faster to just use `dealloc` but then it would crash when the pool is released. is there a way to 'un-autorelease'?

Comment: @Dani: as `autorelease` is just a delayed `release` the 'un-autorelease' would be an additional call to `retain`. This will make you the owner though. Once you 'un-autorelease' an object via `retain` you have the responsibility to `release` it afterwards.

Comment: @Regexident: so calling `[[something retain] release]` will deallocate it instantly?

Comment: @Dani: No, I said that calling `retain` on an `autoreleased` object requires you to later on (after you're done with it) call `release`, as the NSAutoreleasePool is no longer responsible from the moment you un-autorelease the object. While NSAutoreleasePool will still fire its scheduled `release` it won't deallocate as you incremented the retain count by 1 using the un-autoreleasing call to `retain`. `[[something retain] release]` would be `retain count + 1 - 1` and thus have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @Regexident: so there is no way to deallocate it immediately if it was `autorelease`d?

Comment: No. The only way to reduce the lifetime of an autoreleased object is to tightly enclose it with an additional `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; ... [pool drain];`. As soon as it drains your object is gone (unless retained in between).